# Fonts Compatible with Laser Cutting

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

Pretty straightforward question: My friends and I have access to a laser cutter and we are making a word clock. Thus I was wondering if anyone knew of a LaTeX font compatible with laser cutting such as this

[image: a busy cat]

Or if there is any clever way to create them in TikZ using a drawing outline I would be fine with that too.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Nice! All letters made with a non closed curve!

Comment: Yes, that's probably a better way of summarizing it than saying 'laser cut font'.

My first try is going to try to draw a diagonal strike through each closed curve word and see if that looks okay.

Comment: If Xe/LuaTeX is an option you can use any suitable opentype/truetype font.

Comment: You would be better of with a hand picked set of vector graphics converted from actual fonts. That means a WYSIWYG software would serve better rather than this. Since CAD conversion would be much easier.

Comment: I think the @percusse idea could be your best choice, or find something in opentype or truetype and use it with XeLaTeX or LuaTeX as cfr suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're willing to trade time and energy for more control, you can certainly design your own font, or set of letter-like vector graphics. An easier option would be to use one of the many stencil-like fonts available with friendly licenses. Here's something I did with a rather random font obtained from dafont.com. If you look harder than I did, or maybe spend a few bucks on licensing a more professional font, you'll probably be able to obtain results that are even closer to what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Overspray}
\begin{document}
ESKISTLFÜNF\\
HATEINERUND\\
GEMACHTZUWE\\
RDENDERVONB\\
UCHWOLLENUN\\
DDIESEALSON\\
AMENSCHLICH\\
TESONDERNEN
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly want to use [a modern stencil font](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/stencil) in LuaLaTeX with the `fontspec` package.

If for some reason you were forced to use PDFTeX for this, [the LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) has a list of the 8-bit fonts already available for legacy TeX.  However, you don’t have a publisher who’s still forcing you to use legacy tools in 2020.